# Add a class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a particular page loads, these are the state of the `<li>` elements:

```
<li class="li1 frame3" style="display: list-item; opacity: 0.3; left: 0px; top: 20px; z-index: 2;"></li>
<li class="li2 frame4" style="display: list-item; opacity: 0.3; left: 151px; top: 0px; z-index: 2;"></li>
<li class="li3 frame5" style="display: list-item; opacity: 0.3; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 2;"></li>
```

At any point, there is only **one** `<li>` having the `left: 0px; top: 0px`. I want to add a class (say, `.dummy` ) to the `<li>` element that has this property using javascript.

I'm a newbie in Javascript. I tried add ign this:

```
$("li").addClass("dummy");
```

But I couldn't figure out the required `if` statement.

Comment: I'm sure you do. [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: loop thru all `<li>` elements and compare `element.style.left` and `element.style.top`. I am afraid there is no easier way to do it

Comment: @JackManey: Please see the edits, and please remove the down-vote.

Comment: @xan - I'll downvote whenever I please. What do you mean "required `if` statement"? If you want to add a class to an element, then add a class to an element.

Comment: @JackManey: I also need the condition, that when a particular `<li>` element is found to have the property `left:0px; top:0px` apply the `addClass` to that `<li>` element only. I was unable to figure out that condition; how to check for the inline style.

Comment: @xan - Okay, so loop through them and check. What's stopping you?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to add a class name to a DOM element, it goes something like this:

```
var liElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
  var liElement = liElements[i];
  if (liElement.style.top == "0px" && liElement.style.left == "0px") {
    liElement.className += " dummy"; //Add the class name. Notice that the property is not called 'class'
  }
}
```

Edit: Added code to loop through `li` elements...

Answer (score 1):

```
div.classList.add("anotherclass");
```

details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList

Comment: Perhaps you should put the support info for `classList` here. Don't get me wrong, I think `classList` is great, I use it a lot myself, but I'm aware of the fact that I'll need an alternative if I have to support IE9/ IE Mobile.

Answer (score -2):

i'm not sure what you want to do.

but to add a class with jquery you can use this:

```
$(selector).addClass(classname,function(index,oldclass))
```

You can read about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp

Comment: This is not a jQuery question